# 16 bit 2's complement adder in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to add the value for 16 input and 1 output by input and output has 16 bit length.I have 2 types of the input value.

- Binary 16 bit for positive value and sign bit is '0' such as
  "0111000101111000" for (29048).
- 2's complement 16 bit for negative value and sign bit is '1' such as "1000111010001000" for (-29048).

Comment: Terrible phrasing. I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out, **VHDL Math Tricks of the Trade**, which is posted at:  http://www.synthworks.com/papers/